# Angular Multiple subscripts making same API call cause duplicate loads on init

Tags: angular, rxjs

We have to different subscriptions that need to call the same loadData function. Basically if the date changes then load data, also if the filters changes then load data

```
  this.dateInputSubscription = this.filterService.dateInputSubject.subscribe(input => {
    this.loadData();
  }
});

this.filterChangeSubscription = this.filterChangeService.changeSubject.subscribe(data => {
  this.loadData();
});
```

These both subscribe to replay subjects, when the page load and onInit is executed both subscriptions trigger the loadData function which makes an API call, thus making two API calls.

Is there anything in Angular to prevent this?

Comment: one possible workaround is to use `shareReplay()` of rxjs, if data is already available and you want to cached it and display next time without calling new same api call to server.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a [combineLatest()](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/combinelatest.html)

```js
combineLatest(
   this.filterService.dateInputSubject,
   this.filterChangeService.changeSubject
).subscribe(([input, data]) => this.loadData());
```

It will call `this.loadDate()` once when both observables have an initial value, but later call `this.loadDate()` when either emits a value change.